# how to upload file using box.net API?

Tags: php, forms, curl, box-api

Form last 2 days i am trying to fix a issue of uploading a file in Box.net using php.

I have gone through Box.net API Documentation and copied the sample code they have given, the code that they have given- uploads file perfectly, But it redirects to that page where server response is printed(XML response).

I do not want to show user such screen, instead i would like to read those data and based on that response, display message of mine.

I have edited my code as per the guidance given by @GBD, now i am facing another issue.

The file I select does not upload , Instead it uploads some `.tmp file`.
And when i hard code the file path in `$_POST['new_file1']` it successfully uploads correct file.
the file path i get is some thing like this `C:\wamp\tmp\php1A.tmp` not actual file path, when i echo `$_FILES['new_file1']['tmp_name']`.

Can any one tell me how can i get the file path from `$_FILES` ? So that i can pass it to $post

Following is my code:

```
<?php
$upload_url = 'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/i9g1fmnnddfdr4739sxvbpXXXXXXXX/480416060';
$tmpfile = $_FILES['new_file1']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['new_file1']['name']);
$_POST['new_file1'] = '@'.$tmpfile;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
?>
<form action=""
  enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="new_file1" />
<input type="text" name="share" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="upload_files" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure you have the right Content-Type and/or enctype as per the Box API documentation.

Comment: It gives you all the data for debuging. `upload_no_files_found` means exactly what it states and you should've checked if you actually supply any file in a request. If you would do that, you'd find that you actually don't supply any file as in PHP files are in `$_FILES` and not in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php

$tmpfile = $_FILES['new_file1']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['new_file1']['name']);

$_POST['new_file1'] = '@'.$tmpfile;

$upload_url = 'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/i9g1fmnnddfdr4739sxvbpXXXXXXXX/480416060';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But still it does not upload the correct file,instead it uploads some `.tmp` file.Also `$tempfile` has value `C:\wamp\tmp\php1A.tmp` not the actual file location. Please any changes i need to do?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you get any solution for the above point?